# TinyMCE 4 - add custom styles/classes/attributes to any HTML tag

Tags: html, css, tinymce, tinymce-4

Is there any plugin / possibility to allow adding custom attributes to HTML tags by TinyMCE 4 WYSIWYG?

For example, I have added this code via editor (not by the source code):

```
<div dir="ltr">
    <a href="/uploads/myfile.pdf">My file<img src="/uploads/icons/pdf-icon.jpg" alt="My file" width="40" height="40" /></a>
</div>
```

All I need is to add, for example, `class="mypdffile"` or `data-xxx="someval"` attributes to `<div>` tag which is viewed in above code.

How can I do this without changing config object in `tinymce.init`?

Comment: So the current configuration doesn't give you access to the source view?

Comment: It does, but when I edit the code via source and save it, TinyMCE changes source code to it's default value (without my modifications).

Comment: Are you able to make edits to the source of other areas or is it just this one playing up? Have you tried adding a new div with that class instead of editing the outer one?

Comment: Yes I am able to make edits on the source. And yes, I have added new `div` with particular class - it worket. But still... i thought that there exist any user interface for this.

Comment: Usually classes and the like don't have gui controls but have to be done through the source editor - I think the closest thing is adding in page anchor links.

Comment: You cannot do this "without changing the `tinymce.init` config object".

Answer (score 3):

Through the init you can add a styles menu to your editor in which you can create a style which applies to div's and call it `class="mypdffile"`

```
tinymce.init({
    style_formats: [
        {title: 'My PDF file', selector: 'div', classes: 'mypdffile'}
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
tinymce.init({
    extended_valid_elements: '*[class]|*[data-*]'
});
```

According to
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-filtering/#usingextended_valid_elementstoallowscriptelements

The syntax is described here:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-filtering/#valid_elements