# TinyMCE 4 - allow AlpineJS attributes for all HTML tags

Tags: html, tinymce, tinymce-4, alpine.js

I want to allow all Alpine JS components (`x-data`, `x-init`, etc.) as attributes for **all** HTML tags in TinyMCE 4.

I tried to add them via a rule for `extended_valid_attributes` in different ways, but everything fails. Either they are still stripped from the code or they become valid, but all other attributes are then stripped.

Here are some examples of what I already tried, most of it I found in answers to other tinyMCE questions here (e.g. [TinyMCE 4 - add custom styles/classes/attributes to any HTML tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30178060/tinymce-4-add-custom-styles-classes-attributes-to-any-html-tag)) and read in the tinyMCE docs (https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-4x/configure/content-filtering/#extended_valid_elements, https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-4x/configure/content-filtering/#controlcharacters):

```
$alpineAttributes = 'x-data|x-init|x-show|x-text|x-html|x-model|x-for|x-transition|x-effect|x-ignore|x-ref|x-cloak|x-teleport|x-if|x-id';

$settings['extended_valid_elements'] = '*['. $alpineAttributes .']';
```

-> select all elements  via `*`: doesn't work, the alpine attributes still get stripped

```
$settings['extended_valid_elements'] = '@['. $alpineAttributes .'],div,a,p';
```

-> here at least the attributes don't get stripped anymore for `div`, `a` and `p` tags, but *all other* attributes that would normally be allowed for each of those three now get stripped, because the list of allowed attributes doesn't get extended but overriden with my attributes.

```
$settings['extended_valid_elements'] = '@['. $alpineAttributes .'],*';
```

-> doesn't work, the alpine attributes still get stripped

```
$settings['extended_valid_elements'] = '@['. $alpineAttributes .']';
```

-> doesn't work, the alpine attributes still get stripped

Is there really no way to just EXTEND the list of allowed attributes for each element instead of completely overriding it with my rules in `extended_valid_elements`?

Answer (score 4):

We can solve this issue using different strategy. We can change Alpine prefix from `x-` to `data-x-`.
As per the [HTML standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) `x-data, x-init ...` are not valid "custom attributes". The attributes need to have prefix `data-`.
TinyMCE allows `data-*` custom data attributes [by default](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/blob/ab0e8245294da9b7d5a718b4f70235380ae3db97/modules/tinymce/src/core/main/ts/api/html/DomParser.ts#L201), without having to specify them in any rules. So instead of forcing Alpine prefixes on TinyMce we can simply change the prefix on Alpine, using `Alpine.prefix("data-x-")`.

**Demo:** [on codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/alpine-tinymce-pf2cw?file=/index.html:398-456)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #output {
      font-family: monospace;
      font-size: 0.9em;
      color: rgb(83, 23, 23);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/no-api-key/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.8.1/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
  <script>Alpine.prefix("data-x-");</script>

  <p data-x-data="{date:'Date: '+ new Date().toISOString()}" data-x-text="date">date place holder</p>
  <textarea id=editor>Tiny!</textarea>
  <input type="button" id="btn" value="Show editor HTML content" />
  <div id=output></div>


  <script type="text/javascript">
    let content = `<br><p data-x-data="{date: 'Date: '+new Date().toISOString()}" data-x-text="date">date place holder</p>`;

    tinymce.init({
      selector: '#editor',
      schema: 'html5',
      setup: function (editor) {
        editor.on('init', function (e) {
          editor.setContent(content);
          setTimeout(() => Alpine.initTree(editorDOM()), 200);
        });
      }
    });

    btn.onclick = function () {
      output.innerText = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
    }

    function editorDOM() {
      return (editor_ifr.contentWindow
        ? editor_ifr.contentWindow.document
        : editor_ifr.contentDocument).body;
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The alpine `x-text` attribute works inside the editor as well, and it shows current date. This is because TinyMce allows our `data-x-text` attribute.
**Note:**

- In the demo I've used TinyMce latest version 5. It works on version 4 as well. Tested using following CDN:

```html
<script src='https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/no-api-key/tinymce/4/tinymce.min.js'></script>
```

- TinyMCE doesn't work on StackOverflow because of iframe restrictions that is why I've provided the codesandbox link.

Comment: +1 for a very creative solution :D Even though this is not really what we are after, it may be a possible workaround. However, I see some issues with this: First, Alpine.prefix is only available in Alpine v3, not v2. Second, we would need to change the prefix globally, so standard Alpine directives would not work any more. Third, we would need to teach editors to use this custom prefix.

Comment: 2) You can still use Alpine directives like [this](https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine/discussions/2531#discussioncomment-1870888).  In source code, they are doing [the replacement](https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine/blob/fe79ead0081f4911c48e6981868ce1ec5b5b80a6/packages/alpinejs/src/directives/x-bind.js#L7) themselves. 3) If you don't want to concern developers then you can replace the prefix with new one in transpiler. Need to find proper babel plugin.